# jQuery clear Values in a Div

Tags: html, jquery

I have a DIV that contains many input text.

I need a way in jQuery 1.3.2 to clear all the values inside the inputs onclick.

So when I click on a specific link all the values of the inputs inside that DIV will be cleared.

I do not have any sample code, I just need to know if there is a way to clear all the values of inputs that are inside a specific DIV (not in a FORM, but in a DIV).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes there is

html like this

```
<div id="div_id">
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
    <input type="text" value="foo" />
</div>
```

then jQuery

```
$('#div_id input[type="text"]').val('');
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/Car52/)

Comment: Only issue here is it will not clear password, checkbox, radio button fields.

Comment: @Jeremy B good point in which case the OP will need to loop through an make a switch case for the type in order to account for different types

Comment: @JeremyB. in that case $('#div_id input[type="text"']).trigger('reset'); will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What are those inputs? Textboxes? May be this

```
$("#DivID input:text").val("");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PDTGR/)

Answer (score 1):

To clear form element values inside the div use below

```
 function clear_form_elements(id_name) {
  jQuery("#"+id_name).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'file':
        case 'select-one':       
            jQuery(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using val proerpty of the input text elements to blank.

Something like:

```
$("input[type='text']", "#<YOUR_DIV_ID>").val("");
```

e.g:

```
<div id="textDiv">
    <input type="text" Value="1"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" Value="2"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" Value="3"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" Value="4"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" Value="5"/> <br/>
    <input type="text" Value="6"/> <br/>
    <a name="clickMe" href="javascript:void(0)">Empty Boxes</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $("a[name='clickMe']").click(function(){
        $("input[type='text']", "#textDiv").val("");
     });
    });
</script>
```

Check live example @: http://jsfiddle.net/DKwy8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('linkselector').onClick(function() {
    $('#DivId input').val('');
});
```

Comment: that will get the value not set it

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the quotes, damn trying to get the answer done quickly.

Answer (score 0):

try

#### HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" value="One">
    <input type="text" value="Two">
    <input type="text" value="Three">
</div>
<a href="#" name="ClearDiv" id="clearDiv">Clear</a>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('a#clearDiv').bind('click', function() {        
    var $div = $('div#myDiv');
    $('input[type="text"]', $div).each(function() {     
      $(this).val('');
    });

});
```

### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EQhgH/2/)